# Cycle Chain Mode button not show after create chain

Tags: android, android-studio, constraint-layout-chains

I'm using Android Studio 3.4.1.
When i work with ConstraintLayout, i dragged 3 buttons into the layout, select all, and create horizontal chain. But Cycle Chain Mode button not showing after that. So, i can not select other options: Packed, Spread, Spread inside

Is this part removed? or i need setup something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to change the cycle chain mode:

First option: Right click an element in the chain and you'll see a cycle chain mode option.

Second option:

1. Go to the attributes inspector and click the search button.
2. Search for "chain"
3. If not already expanded, expand the layout constraints list.
4. In here you'll find the "layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle" and the "layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle"
5. Clicking on the dropdown button will show you the cycle chain modes that you can use/select.

[image: Attributes screenshot]